# Asp.net Core Blazor - Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor, being relatively new, does not have a lot of documentation on security authentication. In VS 2019, when i create a new Blazor project (server-side or client-side) the authentication options are all disabled.

> What is the authentication solution for organization level security
>   for Blazor apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now no solution is available. The Asp.Net team are working on an Auth system for both flavors of Blazor. Be patient. It is coming soon. Read here what is going on... https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4048

I would invest my spare time polishing my knowledge of the Component model instead, while waiting for the guys in Microsoft to come up with a good solution.

Hope this helps...

[Edit]:
The following is a link to an example of using Identity Authentication with Blazor client-side: https://github.com/stavroskasidis/BlazorWithIdentity

This sample code is fine and all, but I would recommend using JwtToken authentication instead as JwtToken is often used in SPA applications.